# Laravel 5.2 DBLIB driver not supporting

Tags: database, laravel, pdo

I've made sure that the **pdo dblib** driver has been installed correctly on the Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) server that needs to communicate with the SQL Database Server.

This appears that i have done correctly when I run the Command.

```
php -i | grep -i pdo
```

Result

```
PDO drivers => dblib, mysql, pgsql pdo_dblib PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib => enabled
```

But in my original post, I did not see the output above. However, I am still getting d**blib unsupported error**.

can any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to specify "sqlsrv" as the database driver for my db connections not "dblib"